# Multiple foreignkey in Sequelize + Nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have a USERS table in which there are two primary key: id and mail, Users has a relation 1:1 with another table Contacts. I would like to "export" two foreign key in RefreshToken table releated to mail and id.

**USERS table definition:**

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const Users = sequelize.define('Users', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    firstname: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true
    },
    lastname: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function (models) {
        Users.hasOne(models.RefreshToken, {foreignKey:'userId'}
      }
    },
    tableName: 'Users',
    hooks: {
      beforeCreate: user => {
        const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync();
        user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, salt);
      }
    }
  });
```

**RefreshToken table definition:**

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const RefreshToken = sequelize.define('RefreshToken', {
    idRefreshToken: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    token: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: true
    },
    expire: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: true
    }

  }, {
    tableName: 'RefreshToken'
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure without looking at your code, but I think what you're trying to do is this

```
 db.define('user', {/* ... */});
 db.define('contact', {/* ... */});

 db.model('contact').belongsTo(db.model('user'), { as: 'contact' })
 db.model('contact').belongsTo(db.model('user'), { as: 'other' })
 db.model('user').hasOne(db.model('user'), { as: 'contact' })
 db.model('user').hasOne(db.model('user'), { as: 'other' })
```

This should give the contact table two columns, `userId` and `otherId` both referencing the user table. You should be able to call `someUser.getContact()` and `someUser.getOther()`

Comment: I made my question more complete!

Answer (score 0):

What you might be trying to do might look like this:

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const Users = sequelize.define('Users', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    firstname: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true
    },
    lastname: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
  });

  Users.associate = (models) => {
    Users.belongsTo(models.RefreshToken, {
      foreignKey: 'userId'
    });
    Users.belongsTo(models.RefreshToken, {
      foreignKey: 'email'
    });
  };

  return Users;
}
```

I noticed you're using sequelize v3 style, try reading the sequelize docs on how to migrate to v4 which is what is currently supported.

Comment: I receive this error: Unhandled rejection Error: SequelizeDatabaseError: ER_CANNOT_ADD_FOREIGN: Cannot add foreign key constraint